# Apply theme with Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0, themes

So I've been trying for some time to get theming to work in Silverlight 4.

I've added a reference to System.Windows.Controls.Theming.Toolkit and System.Windows.controls.Theming.ShinyRed

Then I went and did something like this:

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:dataInput="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data.Input" xmlns:WebbyDraw="clr-namespace:WebbyDraw" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"     x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage"
    Width="960" Height="700"  mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:shinyRed="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Theming;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Theming.ShinyRed" >
<shinyRed:ShinyRedTheme>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot2">
....
</Grid>
</shinyRed:ShinyRedTheme>
</UserControl>
```

But I always get the same old theme...no errors, but nothing happens either. I've also tried other themes from the Silverlight 4 toolkit, and also tried applying it to a single control...nothing...what am I doing wrong? I've read several tutorials and haven't found the answer.

Comment: Have you tried adding a Resource Dictionary in app.xaml?

Comment: I tried putting the namespace definition (xmlns:shinyRed=") in the app.xaml...but is that all I need to do? that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i use theming, i also allow my users to change to their preferred theme -
you can replace ShinyRed.xaml with any other style resource file to support multiple themes can also be done programmatically(remove one resource dictionary and add another).

In your user control xmal

```
xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit"
<toolkit:Theme x:Name="ThemeContainer">
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
... all other controls in the page
</Grid>
```

Copy all brushes and fonts required for the shinyred theme and create one single Style file called ShinyRed.xaml (you can simply follow the includes in each file to get it all in one file)

So in your App.xaml reference this newly created xaml adn that is it compile and run!

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>

            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>                
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/ShinyRed.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```